# How to echo NLS_LANG varriable shell_exec

Tags: php

```
shell_exec("export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8");
$xa = shell_exec("echo $NLS_LANG");
echo $xa;
```

This code not working, where problems ?

Comment: Please also post the error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because both are running as different processes in different environments.

```
   php
    |___shell 1
    |___shell 2
```

You can manipulate the environment with [`putenv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php).

```
putenv("NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8");
$xa = shell_exec("echo \$NLS_LANG");
echo $xa;
```

Hope this helps.